# MagicChunks not writing web.config attribute

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, web.config-transform, magic-chunks

I have this block in my `web.config`:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove Trailing Slash" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Angular UI Router - HTML5 Mode" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/api/" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

In an Azure release pipeline I'm using the MagicChunks tool to transform the `web.config` to change the second `action` elements' `url` attribute to `"/"` but it is failing. The transform I have is:

```
{
  "rewrite/rules/rule/action[@type='Rewrite' and @url='/app/']/@url": "/"
}
```

The error it throws up is:

```
System.ArgumentException:***There***is***empty***items***in***the***path.
```

How can I target an attribute to be transformed when it is not the attribute(s) being used as the target path?

Comment: When I tested the extension on my side, it throw a warning `[warning]Task 'MagicChunks' (2.0.3) is using deprecated task execution handler.` though it worked well to transform the web.config. Maybe this extension needs some update to meet latest devops extension rule...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your web.config looks like, but there's something wrong with your transform syntax. Check [document](https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/magic-chunks/wiki/XML) from that extension. You should use something like:

```
{
  "rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Angular UI Router - HTML5 Mode']/action[@type='Rewrite']/@url": "/"
}
```

Since I tested your script in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
  </system.web>
  <rewrite>
    ...
  </rewrite>
</configuration>
```

So I actually used something like:

```
{
  "configuration/rewrite/rules/rule[@name='Angular UI Router - HTML5 Mode']/action[@type='Rewrite']/@url": "/"
}
```

Be careful about the root node in your web.config. Then it should work well to replace the `url` attribute to `"/"`. Let me know if I misunderstand anything :)